# Google Picasa error in firefox

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, picasa

I am currently developing the following code

```
List<Album> albums = new List<Album>();
GoogleService googleService = new GoogleService();

        PicasaService picasaService = googleService.CreatePicasaService(accessToken);
        AlbumQuery query = new AlbumQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("default"));
        PicasaFeed feed = picasaService.Query(query);

        foreach (PicasaEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            Album album = new Album();
            album.AlbumTitle = entry.Title.Text;
            AlbumAccessor ac = new AlbumAccessor(entry);
            album.NumberOfPhotos = (int)ac.NumPhotos;
            album.AlbumAuthor = ac.AlbumAuthor;
            album.AlbumAuthorNickname = ac.AlbumAuthorNickname;
            album.AlbumSummary = ac.AlbumSummary;
            album.Id = ac.Id;
            album.Access = ac.Access;
            album.PicUrl = entry.Media.Content.Url;

            albums.Add(album);
        }
```

that code is working fine when i run it in google chrome or in IE but when running it in Firefox i get the following error 
    The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Source Error:

```
Line 56:             PicasaService picasaService = googleService.CreatePicasaService(accessToken);
Line 57:             AlbumQuery query = new AlbumQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(Constants.CurrentUser));
Line 58:             PicasaFeed feed = picasaService.Query(query); <-- the error happened here 
Line 59: 
Line 60:             foreach (PicasaEntry entry in feed.Entries)
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: It seems odd that C# which is 100% seperated by which browser views the result works on IE and Chrome. My guess is that they are more forgiving then Firefox and/or its a setting within Firefox that causing the problem. All you are doing is getting the albums for a given user.  What comes after the for loop?

Comment: fetching each album to get album information title and author etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in query string `Unicode` i fixed this issue by `encoding` the `AlbumQuery` before send it to `QueryFeed`